# Getting Error while executing android program

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to execute program but getting following error.The `xml` is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </ViewFlipper>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/BarLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GoBtn" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/tb_background_top" android:weightSum="0.75"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/WebViewProgress"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:indeterminate="false" style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" android:layout_marginRight="3dip" android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                android:maxHeight="5px" android:minHeight="5px"></ProgressBar>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ToolsBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/fav_icn_default"></ImageButton>

                <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/UrlText"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
                    android:dropDownWidth="fill_parent"
                    android:inputType="textUri"></AutoCompleteTextView>

                <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/GoBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_go"></ImageButton>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/findControls" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="4dip" android:paddingRight="4dip"
            android:paddingBottom="1dip" android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar">

            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_find_prev"
                android:id="@+id/find_previous" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_find_next"
                android:id="@+id/find_next" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_marginRight="6dip">

                    <EditText android:id="@+id/find_value" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:singleLine="true" android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:inputType="text" android:hint="@string/SearchDialog.Hint" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/find_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_close_panel" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/bubbleright48"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:id="@+id/BubbleRightView"></ImageView>

        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/bubbleleft48"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/BubbleLeftView"></ImageView>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/PreviousTabView"
            android:src="@drawable/previous_tab"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"></ImageView>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/NextTabView"
            android:src="@drawable/next_tab"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"></ImageView>        

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/BottomBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tb_background_bottom" android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:weightSum="5">

            <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/PreviousBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons_bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip" 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_next" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>                        
            <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/RemoveTabBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons_bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_close_tab" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>
            <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/QuickBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons_bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_bookmarks" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>           
            <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/NewTabBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons_bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_open_tab" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>
            <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/NextBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons_bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_forward" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>             

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the errors are

```
1)Error:(16) Error: @+id/GoBtn is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout [NotSibling]
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GoBtn" android:layout_width="fill_parent"

2)Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }``
}
...
```

Comment: Remove `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GoBtn"` from your xml file and check whether the error persisits please..

Comment: Or change it to `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/GoBtn"` (no "+"!).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```xml
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/BarLayout"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/GoBtn"
```

You're trying to align this LinearLayout to a button that's contained *inside* this Linear Layout. They are not at the same level inside the RelativeLayout, so they're not siblings. You need to reconsider your layout and relationships between Views.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in this answer but it just a paraprase of oryginal error: `@+id/GoBtn is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout` ... this statement should be obvious for everyone with basic reading skills